# openmp error when using bool array

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

this is the error i'm getting

```
Error   1   error C3028: 'CAlgo::m_CandEnable' : 
only a variable or static data member can be used in a data-sharing clause

bool m_CandEnable[ALGO_NUM_CANDIDATE];
```

this is the pragma im using

```
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)  default(shared) firstprivate(nbr_SAD_RES_index_BNLM_PATCH_LOC_Y_plus_k_offset_BNLM_PATCH_LOC_X, candLocX_index_i, candLocY_index_i,\
                                                    cand_pixel_value, patch_pixel_value, nbr_SAD_RES_candLocY_index_iplus_k_offset_candLocX_index_i,\
                                                    exit_loop_sad_max, fast_SAD_index_i, candLocY,candLocX, i ,j , k)
```

the variable is declared as private. same error for shared

Comment: [data-members-in-an-openmp-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891641/data-members-in-an-openmp-loop)

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you have declared the variable `exit_loop_sad_max` twice in the private statement. Maybe this cause the error?

Do you have other statements declared for the m_CandEnable array (such as threadprivate)? Do you access this array in a critical section within the loop?

Please provide more code or we can only guess.

Comment: no if i was declaring it twice there is a different error for that Error 3 error C3029: 'exit_loop_sad_max' : can only appear once in data-sharing clauses in an OpenMP directive

Comment: can you look at my comment?