# OpenMp: Threadlocal member

Tags: c++, openmp

I am currently working on a piece of code written by a former colleague which utilizes OpenMP. Myself however has no experience with OpenMP and while I understand the very basics by just reading his code, I'm currently stuck figuring out how to declare a threadlocal member for my own modification.

The current code in a very simplified version looks like this:

```
struct Worker
{
    void work() { //... }
};

-------------------------------------------------------------------

Worker worker;

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    worker.work();
}
```

What I want to acheive is to modify the `Worker` class in a way similiar to this:

```
struct Worker
{
    void work() { // m_var is accessed here }
    
    int m_var; // should be threadlocal
};
```

However I have no clue how to achieve this using OpenMP. Notice that all other members inside `Worker` should not be synchronized or threadlocal.

PS: For those who are curious, `Worker` is actually a class to download some complicated stuff and in the for loop the single downloads are performed. `m_var` is going to be an object holding a session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-static data members have separate instances in each instance of the class and cannot be thread-local - they inherit the sharing class of the concrete object of the given class. For example, if an object of class `Worker` is created on the stack of an OpenMP thread (i.e. the object has an automatic storage class), then the object itself is private to that thread and `worker.m_var` is also private. If the object is created on the heap, it could be shared with other threads and `worker->m_var` will then be shared too.

Thread-private can only be applied to data members with static storage class:

```
struct Worker
{
    void work();

    static int m_var;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(m_var)
};

int Worker::m_var;
```

In that case only one static (global) copy of `Worker::m_var` exists and it making it thread-private gives each thread a separate instance shared between all instances of `Worker` in that thread.

Also note that `private` and `firstprivate` cannot be applied to class data members, no matter if they are static or not - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5007203/1374437).

Answer (score 0):

Should the `static` requirement be unacceptable for your situation, you can to replace your `int` field with a class of its own -- the class can be private to your `Worker`, or you can make it a template to be reused with different fields in different classes.

Either way, the new class's constructor will allocate *an array* -- as long as there are OpenMP-threads (let's call it `int_array`):

```
    ThreadedInt() {
        int_array = new int[omp_get_max_threads()];
    }
```

You will also implement the *operators* necessary to cast this new class into the original type (`int` in your example). For example:

```
    operator int() const {
        return int_array[omp_get_thread_num()];
    }
```

as well as some others, such as assignment:

```
    int& operator = (int value) {
        return int_array[omp_get_thread_num()] = value;
    }
```

then the rest of your code can remain unmodified, OpenMP or not.