Can openmp set a smart member pointer as shared among threads?
Is it fine if openmp makes a member pointer to be shared?
Since the pointer has access to a big data,
I only want it to be accessed and modified by each thread, rather than copying.
Does the following code do the job?  It seems strange to make the private member pointer to be shared among threads, but
it is unclear how I can fix it.
Here is my sample code:
class A
{
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<B> B_ {nullptr};

  public: 
    void run () ;
};


void A:run()
{
   #pragma omp parallel shared (B_)
   #pragma omp for
   for(int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
   {
     B_->dataRef(i)=1.0;  
   }
}


shared is the default. The this pointer is already shared and through it, this->B_. And even if it was a local variable, setting it shared would be fine.

To get a better answer you should explain more about what problem you are expecting, at least I do not understand about which potential problem you see.

thank you for editing and clarification. I just saw somewhere  that we cannot set the private member variable to be shared in openmp, see, e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610656/why-is-class-member-variable-x-not-allowed-to-be-sharedx-in-openmp   If I can only use private one in the openmp in this situation, then we need to unnecessary copies of the variable.  This seems not a good idea.  The openmp seems to me rather complicated...

Having copies of a pointer isn't really an issue, only a deep copy would be really inefficient.

Note: If you want to respond someone, write @Name to notify them. Only you as the one who wrote the question are automatically notified. As for the question: You are missing the point: Your method accesses B_ through the this pointer. Writing B_->dataRef is just a short-hand notation for this->B_->dataRef. sharing is also the default if you don't declare anything. The this pointer is automatically shared and cannot reasonably be anything else. So you just overcomplicate things. Simply write #pragma omp parallel for and you are done

Neither gcc nor icx complain if B_ is set as private in the OpenMP region. But private will give you garbage or a segmentation violation: the right clause would rather be firstprivate to initialize the private copies (only the pointer is copied, not the pointed data). But as stated above, shared is fully OK.

And no, OpenMP is definitely not complicated, it's on the contrary a very simple way to use multithreading, and quite easy to learn. Still, it has a learning curve.

@Homer512, this is really a great help. Thanks a lot the clarification.

@paleonix, thanks for help
